# How to make a languages selector button with flag? (html + js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I'm trying to make a language selector button with flags in HTML & JS, but the result I'm getting doesn't match the example I found here: https://codepen.io/brapastor/pen/BWyomB 
The picker selector works, but the flag and the appearance doesn't works. 
What am I doing wrong please ?

```
 <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English'>English</option>
  <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-mx"></span> Español'>Español</option>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'> $(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});</script>
```

Comment: seems like you might be missing the CSS part of this

Answer (score 5):

[Codepen](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/editor/adding-external-resources/) allow for CSS and Javascript libraries to be added from extenal sources, and these libraries are not visible unless you click on the settings/gear link to expose them, here is how you should include them:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English'>English</option>
  <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-mx"></span> Español'>Español</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the codepen you attached, you need to include some stylesheets as follows.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css">
```

Also add the following scripts,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right and your point is well taken. I did add the scripts and stylesheets, but it still doesn't work. I put the styles in the header, the scripts in the body, but the appearance remains the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Close the script tag :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
</script>
```