# How to display only the Image of a Selected Option in HTML Select Element

Tags: html, css

I have the following select element where each of the option elements is made up of an `img` and a `span` as follows

```
<select>
  <option>
  <img src="country-flag"/><span>CountryName</span>
  </option>

  <option>
  <img src="country-flag"/><span>CountryName</span>
  </option>

  <option>
  <img src="country-flag"/><span>CountryName</span>
  </option>
<select>
```

Now when a user picks a country, how do I display only the country flag on the Select Prompt and ignore the text

Comment: you can't do that with html selects, there are 1000 plugins to do that.

Comment: Am I right you want to create a language selector?

Comment: @AdamP. Yes. But only the country flag should be displayed on the Select Prompt Before and After Selection

Comment: obviously did not make the effort of a simple research before publishing

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=select&type=Repositories

Answer (score 0):

You only need to copy code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60606573/6087422) answer and remove language name texts from options

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can not use img tags inside select elements.

You can either use javascript plain/library to mimic the select element or for something simple like countries flags you could use emojies inside the select ->option element.

```html
<select name="countries">
    <option value="Plain flag"></option>
    <option value="DE">&emsp;Germany</option>
    <option value="FR">&emsp;France</option>
    <option value="some emoji"> cool right?</option>
</select>
```

You can search online for emojies to just copy and paste on your script.
For example you can use this free website: https://getemoji.com/