# Making dropdown menu with flags using HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I try to create my first website and I want it to have a dropdown menu with multiple languages.

My site uses only HTML, CSS, and JS. I don't use bootstrap.

I tried to use the codes from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606265/how-to-make-a-languages-selector-button-with-flag-html-js) but the results I got were:

[image]

It does not include the flag and it looks different from the other buttons in the row.

What is did was adding to my main file (index.html) the following:

```js
/* chooseLang
 * ---------------------------------------------------- */
var chooseLang = function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css">

<header id="header" class="row">

  <nav id="header-nav-wrap">
    <ul class="header-main-nav">
      <li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" href="#home" title="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about" title="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#download" title="download">Download</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English'>English</option>
    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-mx"></span> Español'>Español</option>
  </select>

  <a class="header-menu-toggle" href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>

</header>
<!-- /header -->
```

Basically, I wouldn't mind if it even was only 2 flag buttons without a menu.

Comment: Hello Ben, please include any relevant code that can help to reproduce your issue. If you can add a working snippit would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `chooseLang` to a function and to run the code inside a function you need to call/invoke it. Add `chooseLang();` after assigning the variable, and everything will work as intended.

```js
/* chooseLang
 * ---------------------------------------------------- */
var chooseLang = function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
};

chooseLang();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css">

<header id="header" class="row">

  <nav id="header-nav-wrap">
    <ul class="header-main-nav">
      <li class="current"><a class="smoothscroll" href="#home" title="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#about" title="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothscroll" href="#download" title="download">Download</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English'>English</option>
    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-mx"></span> Español'>Español</option>
  </select>

  <a class="header-menu-toggle" href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>

</header>
<!-- /header -->
```

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. Is there a chance that the .css of the header conflicts with the style of the selector? The invoke is used in my INIT function in JS where I call all the other functions.

Comment: @Ben I don't get what you mean by **.css of the header**!

Comment: I have tons of lines in the .css file which affects header-nav-wrap,header-main-nav and more. Maybe it hides the flags? I don't see them...